# How to covert compressed data to initial format data on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've try to get data that compressed to txt format. Here's my dataset

```
1 0 1 01 0 0 00 1 0 1
```

Here's what I want

```
column_1  column_2  column_3   column_4
1         0         1          0
1         0         0          0
0         1         0          1
```

Comment: Have you tried writing code?

Comment: I've try  `rstrip()` and `split()` on pandas, still working on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.array(list(s.replace(' ', ''))).reshape(3,4).astype(int))
```